# python string.format and invalid \x escape

Tags: python, format, escaping, hex

I'm trying to format a string with some `\x` inside in python.

When I use:

```
print '\x00\x00\xFF\x00'
```

it works nicely and print `�`. But when I try to format the string:

```
print '\x{}\x{}\x{}\x{}'.format('00','00','FF','00')
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid \x escape
```

The problem when I escape the backslash like this:

```
print '\\x{}\\x{}\\x{}\\x{}'.format('00','00','FF','00')
```

It prints:

```
\x00\x00\xFF\x00
```

And not the little `�` like the non-formatted string.

`chr` and `bytearray` seem interesting for example:

`print chr(0x00),chr(0x00),chr(0xFF),chr(0x00)` or `print bytearray([0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00])`

prints `�`, but when I try to format them, I get a SyntaxError.

I found some interesting posts like:

- [Why can't Python's string.format pad with "\x00"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741435/why-cant-pythons-string-format-pad-with-x00)
- [Converting int to bytes in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017698/converting-int-to-bytes-in-python-3)

But I'm still stuck...

How to print a formatted string with `\x` inside?

(I'm using python 2.7 but I can use an other version.)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objective is to create a format string that will print characters, given string representations of hex values that correspond to unicode code points, so that something like this

```
for var1 in 'FF','00','38': 
    print '\x{}\x{}\x{}\x{}'.format(var1,'00','FF','00')
```

will output

`��
�
8�`

The trick is to convert the hex values to integers, using the `int` builtin function, then use the `c` string format code to convert the integer value to the corresponding unicode character.

```
for v in ('ff', '00', '38'):
    print '{:c}{:c}{:c}{:c}'.format(*[int(x, 16) for x in [v, '00', 'ff', '00']])

�� 
� 
8�
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

> `c`:  Character. Converts the integer to the corresponding unicode character before printing.